# Inconveniente con localStorage

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Estoy realizando una aplicación en Ionic 3, enlazado a un php-slim-Restful.
En dicha aplicación al realizar el login lo enlace mediante POST a la url del php-slim-resful. Utilicé la siguiente función para que en la consola me guardara los datos (objeto) y así utilizarlos:

```
localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(this.responseData) )
```

Al cerrar sesión (logout) metí la función LocalStorage.clear(); para que se limpiaran los datos con los que había iniciado sesión. El problema aquí es que desde mi pantalla de bienvenida al darle clic en "Ir a iniciar Sesión" me manda este error:

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: data is null
>   c@http ://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:13535 u/<@http ://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:12891 NavControllerBase.prototype._fireError@http://localh ost:8100/build/vendor.js:43269:13 NavControllerBase.prototype._failed@http ://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:43257:9 NavControllerBase.prototype._nextTrns/<@http ://localhost:8100/build

La verdad desconozco el porque de dicho error. ¿Alguien me podría ayudar?
Cabe resaltar que después de que metí el método localstorage.clear(); ese error me salio.

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar el código de login?

Answer (score 0):

Asumo que el error te empezó a aparecer cuando metiste la sentencia de limpiar el `localStorage`, porque si no es así es difícil saber si uno está relacionado con el otro sin ver el resto del código:

Cuando llamas a `localStorage.getItem('userData')`, si el item no existe, obtienes `null`. Es posible que hagas algo como

```
let userData=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData'));
```

y no estés comprobando si la variable es null antes de usarla durante el login.

De todos modos sería más fácil comprobar el error si el código de login lo añadieras a la pregunta (parece que es un problema al resolver una Promise, así que asumo que es algo que ocurre tras hacer una petición AJAX al servidor